# KnockoutJs binding issue on select list

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

I'm using Typescript with KnockoutJs and I am having issues with binding the optionsText and optionsValue. The model is:

```
 export interface LanguageProxy {
    ID: number;
    Name: string;
    Code: string;
    IsSparse: boolean;
    HasAudio: boolean;
    ReadsRightToLeft: boolean;
    IsAsian: boolean;
    ShortCode: string;
    LongCode: string;
    CultureCode: string;
    IsEnabled: boolean;
    IsCustom: boolean;
}
```

we are setting up the binding as (response being a response from a web service call):

```
var langs = ko.observableArray([]);
        response.LanguageProxyListResult.forEach(lang => {
            langs.push(ko.observable(lang));
        });

        this.Languages = langs;
        ko.applyBindings(this, jQuery("#QuickSearchContainer")[0]);
```

and we are binding using the following HTML below:

```
<select name="ddlLanguage" id="ddlLanguage" class="LanguageList"  
                                data-bind="options: Languages,
                                            optionsText: 'Name',
                                            optionsValue: 'ID',
                                            optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
                                            optionsAfterRender: function (e) { jQuery('#ddlLanguage')[0].selectedIndex = 1;}">

                            </select>
```

The data binds correctly, removing the optionsText and optionsValue returns the list of [object] [OBJECT], but when adding the properties of optionsText and value it sets up a blank list.

Looking at a knockoutJs context debugger for chrome, the data appears correctly in the element (under $data.Languages.Symbol(_latestValue) and the parsed context) . Is there something fundamentally I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `options` binding supports observables in the array.

If you replace `langs.push(ko.observable(lang));` by just `langs.push(lang);`, it should work.

There's no real point in wrapping an object in an observable when it's in an observable array.

*Reproduction of problem, note that the second `select` will throw an error.*

```js
var opts = ko.observableArray([
  { name: "Option 1" },
  { name: "Option 2" }
]);


var obsObs = ko.observableArray([
  ko.observable({ name: "Option 1" }),
  ko.observable({ name: "Option 2" })
]);


ko.applyBindings({
  opts: opts,
  obsObs: obsObs
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: opts, optionsText: 'name'"></select>
<select data-bind="options: obsOpts, optionsText: 'name'"></select>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you for explaining the issue, I am still learning the framework.